# how to replace and/or remove div text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to work with this code exactly as it is (below).  I would like to hide/remove all that text in the last two `<div>`(expanded in the code), and write, add or replace it with my new text.  Or just replace one of the last 2 div and remove the other, etc. I hope you got the idea.  Also, the new code needs to be written entirely in the `<head>` section.  It should work automatically on load, so there is no need for buttons to operate the functions.

Thank you very much for any help.

code:

```
<div id="myo-packing-slip-0" class="a-section">
  <div class="a-row a-grid-vertical-align a-grid-center">...</div>
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-micro myo-thank-you">...</div>
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-padding-mini table-border">...</div>
  <table class="a-normal a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small table-border">...</table>
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro a-padding-small a-text-right">...</div>
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-top-base">
<b>Returning your item:</b><br>Go to "Your Account" on Amazon.com, click "Your Orders" and then click the "seller profile" link for this order to get information about the return and refund policies that apply.<br>Visit <a href="https://www.amazon.com/returns">https://www.amazon.com/returns</a> to print a return shipping label.  Please have your order ID ready. 
</div>
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-top-base">
<b>Thanks for buying on Amazon Marketplace</b>. To provide feedback for the seller please visit <a href="http://www.amazon.com/feedback">www.amazon.com/feedback</a>. To contact the seller, go to Your Orders in Your Account. Click the seller's name under the appropriate product. Then, in the "Further Information" section, click "Contact the Seller."
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you include that in the question as well, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: Your code has to work with Amazon divs?  Seems alittle sus.

Comment: *"You got the idea"*: not sure? Can you post exactly what you expect as result, and what should trigger it?

Comment: I updated my answer below (see fiddle at the end). I think this should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been good if you could give some more code. I'm guessing these 2 DIVs are nested, are they? Since your information is very vague, as I said, I assumed 2 things for my snippet (mainly to be able to show better how to get your own text into the respective DIV):

- the two DIVs have a container (are nested)
- there are no other elements in that container (you may use `:nth-child()` otherwise)
- **everything** inside the two DIVs should be deleted/replaced

So, for your intent (remove/replace text) you can use either the **text() method** or the **html() method** in **jQuery**. Both allow you to replace text or just remove it. **Again, everything inside the DIV is replaced/removed.**

jQuery API Documentation:

.text() - https://api.jquery.com/text/
.html() - https://api.jquery.com/html/

```js
/*
  The button is only for demonstration purpose.
*/
$( '#btn-1' ).click( function() {
    /* You only need this part, i.e. something like this */
    $( '.wrapper-or-whatever .a-section:first-child' ).text( '<i>I cannot use HTML here.</i>' );
} ); 
/*
  The button is only for demonstration purpose.
*/
$( '#btn-2' ).click( function() {
   /* You only need this part, i.e. something like this */
   $( '.wrapper-or-whatever .a-section:last-child' ).html( '<i>I can use HTML here.</i>' );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-or-whatever">
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-top-base">
        <b>Returning your item ...</b>
    </div>
    <div class="a-section a-spacing-top-base">
        <b>Thanks for buying ...</b>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="btn-1">Change text of 1st DIV using .text()</button>
<br><br>
<button id="btn-2">Change text of 2nd DIV using .html()</button>
```

Finally, if you're wondering why you need a container, post a comment and I'll add an example.
All that said, happy coding.

**EDIT:** I missed that you wrote "or remove a DIV". So if you want to know how to do that, leave a comment as well, as for now I've only explained how to do it by removing/replacing text.

**UDPATE 2023/05/03:**
Since the OP updated his question, here is a final solution. Both DIVs are now completely removed and the responsible jQuery code is placed **at the very beginning** in the section container. Do not move the jQuery part to the end of that container as it's also a child element. Depending on your environment you may need to change the jQuery identifier `$` (i.e. in WordPress). https://jsfiddle.net/1qkebg4j/

**UDPATE 2023/05/04** (see also the comments):
A last example, where the jQuery part is placed entirely in the `<head>` section. Regarding this, a typo in the OP's question might have prompted him to edit his question again. https://jsfiddle.net/ux9dshjb/

Comment: Thank you very much!

I made a little change to the last code (below) and it works great.  However, when I move it to the <HEAD> it doesn't work, and it is really important for my that the code is placed in the <head>, do you know why it is not working that way?

Comment: Modified last code:
 `<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#myo-packing-slip-0 .a-section:nth-last-child(-n+1)' ).replaceWith("Hello world!");
  });


  $( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#myo-packing-slip-0 .a-section:nth-last-child(-n+1)' ).remove();
  } );
  </script>`

Comment: First, group your code in only one `$(document).ready()` statement. Second, using `.replaceWith()` will remove the entire `<div>` and replace it with whatever (html, text, etc.), just to point that out. If you want to avoid that use `.html()` or `.text()` instead. Third, check if you have included the jQuery Lib and if it's loaded and not getting blocked by CSP or other addons, plugins, etc. Fourth, in your modified code move `$( '#myo-packing-slip-0 .a-section:nth-last-child(-n+1)' ).remove();` above the other statement so it's first. See my new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ux9dshjb/